# TCP Connection Persistence

Tags: networking, tcp, persistence, middleware

I have a client connecting to as server (TCP) and polling data. Whenever the connection drops, i need to reboot the client.

I would like to know if there is any proxy that could be installed on the client computer (windows) that would keep that socket open even tho the connection drops on the other side?

The client itself is not able to automatically bring the connection back on. That's why I am thinking of a middleware that could bring it up on its side:

```
    client ---> middleware ---> server   <- Normal operation

    client ---> middleware -/-> server   <- External failure

    client ---> middleware ---> server   <- We get back up
```

There would be no need to reboot the client everytime.

Thank's,

Comment: If the entire client is being rebooted, no amount of extra software installed on it can possibly survive the reboot, any more than the original software does. What's the *actual* problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebooting the client is overkill.  Have the client connect to the server and then send/receive data.  If the send or receive fails, check the error and close/open the connection to the server and re-send/re-receive.

Simple :)

Comment: Actually the client is a SCADA software. Their built-in way to deal with socket is... not that good. I would have done it that way if possible but i have to restart the SCADA everytime.